# Оставить в текстовом файле только нужные строки PHP

Tags: php

Есть текстовый файл в котором произвожу замены через регулярку, примерно так:

```
$arr_finished = file($work_file);
        $names2 = ['/(\(([^>]+)\))/'];
        foreach($arr_finished as $key => $text2) {
          $text2 = preg_replace($names2, "", $text2);
          $arr_finished[$key] = $text2;}
```

Много примеров есть в интернете где можно заменить любой текст на другой. А вот если мне например нужно в текстовом файле оставить только нужные строки то как это сделать? Например есть список доменов:

- сайт.ру
- суб.суб.сайтик.ру
- пример.ру
- домен-домен.ру
- поддомен2.сайта.ру

Как мне например оставить только домены второго уровня:

- сайт.ру
- пример.ру
- домен-домен.ру

Большое спасибо.

Comment: прочитать строки, отобрать нужные через, например, регулряку, сохранить результат в файл

Comment: А вот это "отобрать" можете подсказать как, остальное попробую сам.

Comment: Читаем файл построчно Регулярку именно в данном случае можно заменить на поиск в строке одной точки. Функция substr_count

Comment: А можно хоть какой то пример, под переделку, а то в php не силен. Про функцию почитал, но как реализовать не понимаю.